# Integration of keycloak with Apache knox

Tags: keycloak, ambari, apache-knox

I am using Ambari application and i am using knox service in it. but i want to use keycloak for authenticate user. how i can integrate keycloak with Apache knox. i folow this article https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Configure-Knox-with-OpenID-Connect/ta-p/247758

but it is not working.

can anyone guide me how is it work in details